# handling the new line in php and sql

Tags: mysql, sql, newline

i am trying to copy a mysql data field which contain new line to another mysql table
using php

I try as

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT data from table1 where id = 100";
$mydata = --------------------- // here I got the data which contain new line.

$updatesqlquery = "UPDATE table2 set data=$mydata where id = 500";
// here the updated data is not same as the frist data.
```

Anyone please kindly guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$updatesqlquery = "UPDATE table2 set data='".mysqli_escape_string(str_replace("\r","",$mydata))."' where id = 500";
```

or you can do it all in one SQL:

```
UPDATE table2 t2
  JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.id = 100
   SET t2.data = t1.data
 WHERE t2.id = 500
```

Comment: I can not use the second option as they are on different server. I am trying the first now.

Comment: Please, whenever possible use parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Calling the escaping function manually is a last resort.

Comment: when inserted it insert as \r\n but I want to insert as new line

Comment: so, change "$mydata" to "str_replace("\r", "", $mydata )"